# select_tag with options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My platform is: 
Windows7 x64,
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32],
 
Rails 2.3.8

```
<%= select_tag 'locale', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale),
    :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
```

LANGUAGES looks like:

```
LANGUAGES = {
  'English' => 'en',
  "Espa\xc3\xb1ol" => 'es'
}
```

Despite the fact, that I18n.locale is equal to 'en', 'English' value is not selected.

```
<select id="locale" name="locale" onchange="this.form.submit()">
   <option value="es">Español</option>
   <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

I'm totally stuck. I can't figure out what's the problem. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I have figured it out. I had to add **to_s**:

```
options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s)
```

Thanks, Alpha.

Comment: If you figured it out by yourself, please write an accepted answer to your own question. That way, this question will pop out from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add to_s:

```
options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s)
```